# MongoDB : 2.6.3 Exception: BSONElement: bad type 101 On repair Database

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, bson, mongotemplate

When i repair my mongo database using following command :

```
> db.repairDatabase()
```

I get an following Error :

```json
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: BSONElement: bad type 101",
        "code" : 10320,
        "ok" : 0
}
```

Can anyone explain why this error occured? 
Also because of which collection and which record this error occured?